# Folder Explorer with Folder Synchronization and Folder Size

Tags: sync, file-management

Is there a folder explorer software that has folder synchronization  and folder size capabilities? Often I need to use them very much and would like to have a single software that can do that.

Does anyone have any experience or idea?

**EDIT**

[This](http://www.softwareok.de/?seite=faq-Q-DIR&faq=40) one gives some hint but I do not understand the language. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [**Unreal Commander**](http://x-diesel.com/) does what I was looking for. It has wealth of features including

1. folder size
2. directory sync
3. Visual Filter based on the extension

[The website](http://x-diesel.com/whatsnew.php?) has the details of the features it has.

Answer (score 0):

[FreeCommander](http://www.freecommander.com/) for instance allows for folder synchronization. Not sure what you mean by "size capabilities".

Comment: Q-Dir is my favorite. But I could not find this folder sync there. Can you please point me to the command or menu item? By size capabilities I mean the software should display size of both files and folders

Comment: I knew this regarding FreeCommander. But do you understand what does the following mean http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Q-DIR&faq=40

Comment: Sorry, I had confused Q-Dir and FreeCommander. FreeCommander can synchronize folders, while Q-Dir can't. FreeCommander is also capable of displaying folder sizes in the details view, although I wouldn't recommend actually using this feature, because calculating the directory size takes some time.

Comment: Even Q-Dir shows folder size (See *Extra* Menu)

Comment: @Stat-R In Q-Dir you can define shortcuts to external commands (`Extras > ... more options > Quick-Links`). What they suggest there is such a quick-link that will run the `xcopy` command. I'd definitely prefer FreeCommander's synchronization feature, though, because it allows for two-way synchronization and also for de-selecting files/folders you want to exclude from synchronization.